# Checksum for datetime field in SQL

Tags: sql, checksum

Task: 
We are validating the data in 2 different tables (of same structure). We tried to use the checksum function on the records for this.

Problem:
The records in the table are same. But when we use the checksum(*), it gives different CheckSum.

```
SELECT statusName,CheckSum(*) from OrderStatus
```

If i calculate the checksum, excluding the DateTime column, it gives the same value in both tables.

```
SELECT statusName,CheckSum(StatusName,CreatedByUser,ModifiedByUser) from OrderStatus
```

Columns in Tables:
StatusName,CreatedByUser,ModifiedByUser,CreatedDateTime,LastModifiedTime

How to resolve this, by including the datetime column.

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Comment: Have you verified that the DateTime values are actually the same between the matching records of the two tables?

Comment: Yes. I copied some data from source to destination, to validate the query.So the data in destination is exact replica of source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a checksum, the order of the columns makes a difference.

Replace the * in the first query with the exact same list of columns.  `CheckSum` should work on date and datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working for me.  Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39c84/1).

I suspect something is off with your DateTime columns -- run this to see if anything is different:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderStatus OS1
LEFT JOIN OrderStatus OS2 ON OS1.CreatedDateTime = OS2.CreatedDateTime AND OS1.LastModifiedTime=OS2.LastModifiedTime
WHERE OS2.LastModifiedTime IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT statusName,
CheckSum(CreatedByUser,ModifiedByUser,CreatedDateTime,LastModifiedTime) 
from OrderStatus
```